# What is the alternative for BYW98 diode?

Tags: pcb, diodes, driver, alternatives

We are using a driver circuit (L6203), however though, the diode in the device is broken, and we can not find the exact diode on the market. Would any body please, suggest an alternative diode for BYW98 diode?
I would appreciate any comments.
My datasheet is 
[here](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/Datasheets/L6203.pdf).

Comment: How about a link to the data sheet?

Comment: That diode was chosen because it fulfills some unknown requirements. There is likely no exact match, so these requirements must be known to recommend a diode that matches those. Oh btw. recommendation of product questions here are offtopic.

Comment: Anyway. If you look at Ebay you can find the diode you want.

Comment: Do you understand specs? what do you need?  ( besides superfast and hi V)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the datasheet and now I have A few suggestions for you.
SF30DG - BVY28 - BYM36A - BYT56D - BYW95A - FE3D - SBYV28 - SF5402 - UG4D
But my experience was the decision to replace the diode to give you the best offer. And it is: SB560

Comment: SB560 is about 10x greater Trr than original.  Mine are less than original so better for low transition losses

Answer (score 2):

Mall Lawyers would charge $50 for this free service.  Don't abuse it.

STMicroelectronics STTH302  is suitable with <20ns reverse recovery time at voltages from 100 to 600V and wide range of currents like 6A
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/STTH3R02AFY/497-15974-2-ND/5418230

BYW98 diode and many like it are obsolete.

I trust you understand the importance of ultra fast reverse recovery times and improved products avail displacing obsolete parts .

Comment: The diode is obsolete. This does not mean no longer available from stock surplus. What is wrong with looking at Ebay. There you can find the diode from many different places. So why select a replacement.

Comment: no reason except better parts are avail at low cost